# Adobe AfterEffect animation in Android app

Tags: android, animation, after-effects

I'd like to make my own loading screen for android applications, probably to show it in a splash screen or during GUI updates.
I followed some tutorials and i was able to create a loading animation in AfterEffect. Than i can export it in any format with Adobe MediaEncoder.

I already tried to export it in a collection of Png files which i can show with android FrameAnimation, but i always get a Memory Error.

Which format should i use and how i can implement it in the android app?

Comment: maybe [this](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android)  library can help you, otherwise you can load a gif